# Uma página com lista de outras páginas

Tags: ionic3, paginação

Gostaria de saber como que eu faço, por exemplo,pagina que irá listar as outras páginas:APP,SITE,etc:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';


/*navParams receive params one page for other page  */
@Component({
  selector: 'page-list',
  templateUrl: 'list.html'
})
export class ListPage {
  selectedItem: any;
  icons: string[];
  items: Array<{title: string, note: string, icon: string}>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    // If we navigated to this page, we will have an item available as a nav param
    this.selectedItem = navParams.get('item');

    // Let's populate this page with some filler content for funzies
    this.icons = ['flask', 'wifi', 'beer', 'football', 'basketball', 'paper-plane',
    'american-football', 'boat', 'bluetooth', 'build'];

    this.items = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
      this.items.push({
        title: 'Item ' + i,
        note: 'This is item #' + i,
        icon: this.icons[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.icons.length)]
      });
    }
  }

  itemTapped(event, item) {
    // That's right, we're pushing to ourselves!
    this.navCtrl.push(ListPage, {
      item: item
    });
  }
}
```

-------------------Html--------------
    
      
        
          
        
        Nossos produtos

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemTapped($event, item)">
      <ion-icon [name]="item.icon" item-start></ion-icon>
      {{item.title}}
      <div class="item-note" item-end>
        {{item.note}}
      </div>
    </button>
  </ion-list>
  <div *ngIf="selectedItem" padding>
    You navigated here from <b>{{selectedItem.title}}</b>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Este código acima é o do padrão do template sidemenu.

O que eu quero fazer é que este array de item contenha as páginas: APP, Site, etc, ai a pessoa clica em por exemplo, APP, vai para ela.

Seria algo como :

```
items = [
      { title: 'Aplicativo', component: AppPage},

      { title: 'Site', component: SitePage},
    ];

  itemSelected(page) 
  {
    this.navCtrl.push(page.component);
  }
}
```

Alguém me dá um help?Obrigada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
itemTapped(event, item) {
    this.navCtrl.push(ListPage, {
      item: item
    });
  }
  
  /// OUUU
  
  /*
  itemTapped(event, item) {
    this.navCtrl.push(item);
  }
  */
```

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemTapped($event, item.component)">
      <ion-icon [name]="item.icon" item-start></ion-icon>
      {{item.title}}
      <div class="item-note" item-end>
        {{item.note}}
      </div>
    </button>
  </ion-list>
  <div *ngIf="selectedItem" padding>
    You navigated here from <b>{{selectedItem.title}}</b>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Você está passando o objeto (item) inteiro na função itemTapped, mas não está referenciando o atributo 'component' deste objeto na hora de fazer o navCtrl.push(). Tive de fazer a alteração no HTML, passando o item.component como segundo parametro da função itemTapped.